# Uploading multiple records to a related tab for a specific ID

Tags: data-loader, upload, updaterecord

[image]everyone!
I've recently started working on a project and there's an issue where I'm stuck and need help with.

Scenario:
I've an excel sheet where there hundreds of types of House Numbers.

For every house number in the sheet, there are various attributes (columns), eg: Attr 1, Attr 2, Attr 3, etc. And for every attributes there's a value.

What I want to do:
I have an object named housing and has a tab. So in the lighting, when I open it, I want the header to contain the house number.

And for that header, I want to create related records, where every record maps to an attribute and its value.

I've created the header and using Data Loader, Ive extracted the record IDs for every record created in the header.

Now, using data Loader, I want to upload these multiple attributes as related records to each header ID.

My senior told me that I'd need to create and excel CSV for every attribute and upload it separately.

But I'm hoping there's some method where I can just upload all of it at once.

If anyone needs a further clarification, I'll post it here. If you understand my query, please do help.

Thank you!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hi, I've added more clarity to the question with a graphical representation. Let me know if that helps

Answer (score 0):

From my reading of your issue, you'll need at most two csv files: only one if (a) the attributes you're talking about are all fields on the base object, only one if (b) there's an "attribute" *object* that you want to add records to that happen to be related to the relevant house numbers; (c) two files if there's some mix of both.

It sounds like you're in the (b) situation, given that you're referring to the "related" list.

So, concrete example:
You have accounts, and you have addresses.
The (a) situation is "every account has a billing address and a shipping address": your csv is going to be an up*date* file, for accounts.

The (b) situation is "accounts might have no addresses, might have four, might have forty": your csv is going to be an up*load* file, for addresses, and there's going to be a column in there for "Account ID" to match up each address with the account that it's referring to.

PS: To get those account IDs, if you only have account *names* to start, you might first need to do an export of your account names + IDs so you can match the one to the other.